# how can i check hashcode and th amount

Tags: solidity, payable, transfer, bytecode, escrow

I'm new in Solidity, therefore if I have a wrong concept of anything kindly do explain.

I'm working for a personal escrow smart contract that should include these functions:

1- function deposit from the owner wallet to the smart contract

2- function gethash
this function requires (amount) and returns hashcode

- amount should not equal 0

3- function transfer amount to address
this function requires (hashcode, address)

- the amount is taken from the hashcode generated by gethash function
- check that hashcode is not in conflict or used before

4- function withdraw to withdraw all money in the smart contract to the owner

I use this code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract mypayable {

   // Payable address can receive Ether
    address payable public owner;

    // Payable constructor can receive Ether
    constructor() payable {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function deposit() public payable {}

  uint deposit_count;
  mapping(bytes32 => uint256) balances;
  function getHash(uint amount) public view returns(bytes32 result){
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, deposit_count, amount,block.timestamp));
  }

  
  function transferto(address payable _to, bytes32 trx_hash, uint amount ) external {

    balances[trx_hash] = amount;
    deposit_count++;

      // Transaction hash cannot be empty
    require(trx_hash[0] != 0, "Transaction hash cannot be empty!");
    // Escrow amount cannot be equal to 0
    require(amount != 0, "Escrow amount cannot be equal to 0.");

    // Transaction hash is already in use
    require(balances[trx_hash] == 0, "Unique hash conflict, hash is already in use.");
    // Transaction hash cannot be empty
    require(trx_hash[0] != 0, "Transaction hash cannot be empty!");
    // Check if trx_hash exists in balances
    require(balances[trx_hash] != 0, "Escrow with transaction hash doesn't exist.");
    // Transfer escrow to sender
   // require(_token.transfer(msg.sender, balances[trx_hash]), "Escrow retrieval failed!");
    (bool success, ) = _to.call{value: balances[trx_hash]}("");
        require(success, "Failed to send Ether");

    // If all is done, status amounts to 0
    balances[trx_hash] = 0;
  }

    function withdraw() public {
        // get the amount of Ether stored in this contract
        uint amount = address(this).balance;

        // send all Ether to the owner
        // Owner can receive Ether since the address of the owner is payable
        (bool success, ) = owner.call{value: amount}("");
        require(success, "Failed to send Ether");
    }


}
```

- functions deposit and withdraw work correctly no issues
- function gethash returned hash code correctly and changeable
- I guess the whole issue in function transferto:

firstly: I added parameter {amount} because I didn't know how to get the amount value from gethash function

second: I faced this error when I tried the transferto function

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? 
execution reverted: Unique hash conflict, hash is already in use.
{
  "originalError": {
    "code": 3,
    "data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002d556e69717565206861736820636f6e666c6963742c206861736820697320616c726561647920696e207573652e00000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "message": "execution reverted: Unique hash conflict, hash is already in use."
  }
}
```

What is the best way to generate and store code/hashcode including amount value and check it in another function like transferto function?

so the withdrawal will input his address and code I provide it
and he will receive the exact amount in gethash function

if there's something missing please tell me to clear more
Thanks in Advance

**----------------------------
update**

I would like to thank (Jeremy Then) for his helping

the message error was gone, but there's something wrong

the hashcode is valid forever not expired
I can send many transactions in the same hashcode and this is not logical
[image: first transaction]
[image: second transaction]

Also, If I input the amount in the gethash function with different values of the amount in transferto, the code will take the amount value of the transferto function
[image: different values]

**I would like if can take the amount from the gethash function and delete the parameter (amount) from the function transferto.**

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that you are doing in the `transferto` function is:

```js
balances[trx_hash] = amount;
```

But then, you do this check:

```js
require(balances[trx_hash] == 0, "Unique hash conflict, hash is already in use.");
```

Which is not compatible with `balances[trx_hash] = amount;`, becase you already added data to the `balances[trx_hash]`, and then you `require` it to be empty, but it's not empty because you just assigned an amount to it. That's the problem.

Maybe you need to add `require(balances[trx_hash] == 0, "Unique hash conflict, hash is already in use.");` before `balances[trx_hash] = amount;`, what do you think?

By the way, I don't think this check is right:

```js
require(trx_hash[0] != 0, "Transaction hash cannot be empty!");
```

Because it is literally just checking the first byte of the `trx_hash`, and in really that first byte could be 0 and all the other bytes could have value.

For example, this check would fail for a valid hash like this: `0x00f6c4584609ab7d77c6af1a7d07a765ffb7d8f5bcec07c613a6c9f6fb00729b`, notice the first byte is `00`, but it's a valid hash that the `keccak256` could return.

So, better do this:

```js
require(trx_hash != 0, "Transaction hash cannot be empty!");
```

Here we are comparing the whole 32 bytes of `trx_hash` value with 0. If all the 32 bytes of `trx_hash` are empty, then its value is 0 and we can compare it with `0`.

For your `transferto` function to work, it should look something like this:

```js
function transferto(address payable _to, bytes32 trx_hash, uint amount ) external {

    require(balances[trx_hash] == 0, "Unique hash conflict, hash is already in use.");

    balances[trx_hash] = amount;
    deposit_count++;

      // Transaction hash cannot be empty
    require(trx_hash != 0, "Transaction hash cannot be empty!");
    // Escrow amount cannot be equal to 0
    require(amount != 0, "Escrow amount cannot be equal to 0.");

    // Transaction hash is already in use
    
    // Transaction hash cannot be empty
    //require(trx_hash[0] != 0, "Transaction hash cannot be empty!");
    // Check if trx_hash exists in balances
    require(balances[trx_hash] != 0, "Escrow with transaction hash doesn't exist.");
    // Transfer escrow to sender
   // require(_token.transfer(msg.sender, balances[trx_hash]), "Escrow retrieval failed!");
    (bool success, ) = _to.call{value: balances[trx_hash]}("");
        require(success, "Failed to send Ether");

    // If all is done, status is amounted to 0
    balances[trx_hash] = 0;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering

I did what you mention and the error is gone

but there's something wrong 

I get the hash code and tried to transfer

I input the same address, amount, and hashcode many times, and its transfer 
every time 

the hashcode should be invalid after being used one time

excuse my bad English

Comment: Check the update.